# Androidx project not building after adding the new room 2.2.2 dependencies

Tags: android, android-room, androidx, android-jetpack

I have been using `Room` for sometime now, having used `Realm` for a number of years I could not help but notice that `Room's` implementation of `UpdateOrInsert` is a bit off. It is completely removing the old record and adding a new one instead of updating the old one, when this happens my `autoGenerate` ID of the so called "updated" field is lost, that said I took a walk on the internet and found myself implementing this [solution](https://tech.bakkenbaeck.com/post/room-insert-update). I am a `Java` guy to say so I had to convert it to Java and the result was

```
@SchedulerSupport(value = SchedulerSupport.IO)
@Dao
public abstract class BaseDao<T> {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract Long insert(T item);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract List<Long> insert(List<T> items);

    @Update
    abstract void update(T item);

    @Update
    abstract void update(List<T> items);

    @Transaction
    public void insertOrUpdate(T item) {
        Long id = insert(item);
        if (id == -1L)
            update(item);
    }

    @Transaction
    public void insertOrUpdate(List<T> objList) {
        List<Long> insertResult = this.insert(objList);
        List<T> updateList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < insertResult.size(); i++)
            if (insertResult.get(i) == -1L)
                updateList.add(objList.get(i));

        if (!updateList.isEmpty())
            this.update(updateList);
    }

}
```

I then made my model

```
@Builder
@Entity
@TypeConverters({Address.Type.class})
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class Address {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int uuid;
    @Ignore
    private String placeUuid;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    private Type type;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "icon")
    private int icon;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_address_available")
    private boolean isAddressAvailable;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lat")
    private double lat;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lng")
    private double lng;
}
```

Finally I linked the two like

```
@Dao
public abstract class AddressDaoImpl extends BaseDao<Address>{
}
```

All was fine until I tried to compile this with `pre-AndroidX versions of Room` dependencies

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1"
```

The compiler complained that I needed to implement `abstract List<Long> insert(List<T> items)` after a google search I finally found a solution. I was using the wrong `Room dependencies`, all my other dependencies were AndroidX except these, for some reason, it turns out they do not get updated as often as the `AndroidX` versions so I updated to the new `2.2.2` and they look like

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.2'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.2'
```

After migrating to these dependencies the error vanished but a new one showed up, now I am facing this error which I do not even understand how I can fix it

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:154)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:122)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.kt:237)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My full `Top level gradle` file looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ubuntu.software.tamanga"
        minSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //MultiDex
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    //Material
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3'


    //Navigation component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.0-rc02"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.0-rc02"

    //Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'


    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'

    //Permissions
    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.2'

    //OkHttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.0'

    //RxJava & RxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10'


    //JWT
    implementation 'com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:1.3.0'

    //Google places
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'


    /* lifecycle & live data*/
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:2.1.0'


    //Paging
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.0'


    //Guava
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android'

    //Dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.25.2"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.25.2"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.25.2"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.25.2"

    //Lombok
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'


    //Phone code picker
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.3.2'

    //enter pin view
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.3'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'


    //RxJava, RxAndroid & RxBinding
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:2.2.0'

    //Shared prefs
    implementation 'com.scottyab:secure-preferences-lib:0.1.7'

    //room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.2'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.2'

    //Places and maps
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

    //Kotlin
    //implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If you have faced a similar problem please help.

Comment: There must be some other build error messages

Comment: @sonnet what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Sonnet was right, there was an error in my code, the error was it was still complaining about the abstract methods that were not overriden in my `abstract BaseDao`. At this point I was left with only one solution; to make an `interface` version of my `BaseDao` containing all my method definitions and implement the ones I was interested in, in `BaseDao which i renamed to BaseDaoImpl` like

```
@SchedulerSupport(value = SchedulerSupport.IO)
@Dao
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T> implements BaseDao<T> {

    @Transaction
    public void insertOrUpdate(T item) {
        Long id = insert(item);
        if (id == -1L)
            update(item);
    }

    @Transaction
    public void insertOrUpdate(List<T> objList) {
        List<Long> insertResult = this.insert(objList);
        List<T> updateList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < insertResult.size(); i++)
            if (insertResult.get(i) == -1L)
                updateList.add(objList.get(i));

        if (!updateList.isEmpty())
            this.update(updateList);
    }

}
```

The interface

```
@SchedulerSupport(value = SchedulerSupport.IO)
@Dao
public interface BaseDao<T> {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    Long insert(T item);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    List<Long> insert(List<T> items);

    @Update
    void update(T item);

    @Update
    void update(List<T> items);

}
```

Then I used it in my Address Dao like

```
@Dao
public abstract class AddressDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<Address> implements AddressDao {


}
```